# как реализовать программу для удаление куки

Tags: javascript, cookie, bom

ЗАДАЧА:
Создать страницу, которая выводит все имеющиеся cookie в виде таблицы (имя, значение).
Для каждой cookie в таблице, необходимо добавить кнопку "удалить", При нажатии на "удалить", на экран должен быть выведен confirm с текстом "Удалить cookie с именем …?". Вместо … необходимо подставить имя удаляемой cookie. Если пользователь ответил положительно, то соответствующая cookie должна быть удалена.

Comment: и ещё как реализовать функционал "добавить куки"?

Comment: К ответам на вопрос добавлю что не все куки доступны из Javascript. HttpOnly-куки нельзя прочитать. http://prophet.ru/2010/12/httponly-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

Вот то, что вы хотели:

```js
(function (Cookies) {

  if (!Cookies) {
    alert('Библиотека "Cookies", необходимая для работы, не найдена.');
  
    return;
  }

  var _wrapper = document.getElementById('cookie-wrapper');
  
  if (!_wrapper) {
    alert('Контейнер для вывода таблицы с Cookie не был найден.');
  
    return;
  }
  
  function generateRow (cells) {
    var _row = document.createElement('tr');

    cells.forEach(function (cellData) {
      var _cell = document.createElement('td');
      
      if (cellData.className) {
        _cell.className = cellData.className;
      }
      
      if (cellData.content) {
        if (cellData.content instanceof HTMLElement) {
          _cell.appendChild(cellData.content);
        } else {
          _cell.innerHTML = cellData.content;
        }
      }

      _row.appendChild(_cell);    
    });
    
    return _row;
  }
  
  function generateAddCookieRow () {
    var _nameField = document.createElement('input');
    _nameField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    _nameField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Введите название cookie...');
  
    var _valueField = document.createElement('input');
    _valueField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    _valueField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Введите значение cookie...');
  
    var _addBtn = document.createElement('button');
    _addBtn.innerHTML = 'Добавить';
    _addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var nameValue = _nameField.value;
      var valueValue = _valueField.value;

      if (!nameValue.length) {
        alert('Вы не заполнили поле "Название".');
        
        return;
      }

      if (!valueValue.length) {
        alert('Вы не заполнили поле "Значение".');
        
        return;
      }
      
      Cookies.set(nameValue, valueValue);
      
      recalculateTable();
    });
  
    return generateRow([
      {
        content: _nameField,
        className: 'cookies__cell'
      },
      {
        content: _valueField,
        className: 'cookies__cell'
      },
      {
        content: _addBtn,
        className: 'cookies__cell'
      }
    ]);
  }
  
  function removeCookie (e) {
    var cookieName = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-name');
    
    var result = confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить cookie "' + cookieName + '"?');
  
    if (result) {
      Cookies.remove(cookieName);
    
      recalculateTable();
    }
  }
  
  function generateTable () {
    var _table = document.createElement('table');
    _table.className = 'cookies';
  
    _table.appendChild(
      generateRow([
        {
          content: 'Название',
          className: 'cookies__cell cookies__cell-head'
        },
        {
          content: 'Значение',
          className: 'cookies__cell cookies__cell-head'
        },
        {
          className: 'cookies__cell'
        }
      ])
    );

    var cookieList = Cookies.get();
  
    for (var cookieName in cookieList) {
      if (cookieList.hasOwnProperty(cookieName)) {
        var cookieValue = cookieList[cookieName];
       
        var _removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
        _removeBtn.setAttribute('data-name', cookieName);
        _removeBtn.innerHTML = 'Удалить';
       
        _removeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeCookie);
      
        _table.appendChild(
          generateRow([
            {
              content: cookieName,
              className: 'cookies__cell'
            },
            {
              content: cookieValue,
              className: 'cookies__cell'
            },
            {
              content: _removeBtn,
              className: 'cookies__cell'
            }
          ])
        );
      }
    }
    
    _table.appendChild(
      generateAddCookieRow()
    );

    return _table;
  }
  
  function recalculateTable() {
    _wrapper.innerHTML = '';
    _wrapper.appendChild(generateTable());
  }
  
  recalculateTable();
  
})(window.Cookies);
```

```css
.cookies {
  width: 100%;
  
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.cookies__cell {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.cookies__cell-head {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<div id="cookie-wrapper"></div>
```

Stackoverflow по соображениям безопасности не даст запустить код прямо отсюда из-за работы с cookie, поэтому протестировать код можете тут:
    https://jsfiddle.net/danilvalov/de7rrfLk/

Единственное, вместо того, чтобы напрямую с document.cookie работать, использовал библиотеку Cookies. Но написать собственные методы get/set/delete не составит проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie
```

Делаем `Split` по `";"`

Получаем `cookie (Название=Значение)`